# Googlemaps Qlikview server not retrieving all the maps

Tags: security, google-maps, ip, google-maps-static-api, qlikview

I'm working with Qlikview and I created this application that shows my service centers around the world, and what they are capable of.

In the desktop version inside the company works fine.

When it goes to the server edition, not all maps works :

- Some say that we need every IP adress from google.
- Some other say that when I choose some selection, it doesnt go to the same URL (maps.googleapis.com), si, the server blocks it.
- Some other say that the google IPs change alot, thats the main problem.

I am confused, I need some information on that :

- How does this outside of my company work, at google ?
- Does everyone experience this IPs change problem ?
- Does google maps access any other different URL, depending on the selection and move in the map ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the way ou are using it is probably wrong, you should never use IP's but instead use dns names.

Please check the qlikcommunity for examples of proper ways to do this.. Other than that I cannot help without seeing the code in the scatter chart.